# How to trigger a popup message in PHP?

Tags: php

I know the question has been asked over and over, but I cannot figure out what am I doing wrong:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
<body>

<?php

echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('message successfully sent');</script>";

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Instead of a pop-up, this is what I see:
[image]

Comment: Change `script language='javascript'` to `script type='text/javascript'`

Comment: Are you sure PHP is executed at all in your file?

Comment: View the source, I think your PHP is not being rendered so your `script` is not an element and you actually have `<?php

echo "<script language='javascript'>` as an element....It is strange that the quotes changed between your code and screenshot..

Comment: What webserver are you running?

Comment: The page could be a .html ext

Comment: @AndFisher AWS php7.0-cli

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile I thought it had to be .html...isn't php embedded in an html alright?

Comment: the ext should be .php then the php code will get interpreted

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile How would it interpret `<html>`?

Comment: .php extension you are telling the web server, that it should use a php interpreter to process the file before it will be delivered to the browser.

Comment: Whether PHP can be executed in .html would be down to the apache configuration. whats your virtualhost setup look like?

Comment: @Dambo the html tags, will be interpreted by the browser

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile That was it, btw. Thanks!

Comment: Great glad your problem could be fixed

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
echo "<script>alert('message successfully sent');</script>";
```

or

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('message successfully sent');</script>";
```

Both works in my case.

Comment: doesn' work for me

Comment: Are you sure you are using a browser that has javascript in it or maybe you have javascript disabled

Comment: @RiggsFolly he's file is saved as .html, check the comments above

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile That will teach me to not read all the comments before getting involved. ;)

Comment: lol @RiggsFolly true that.. The Op's problem is fixed, I don't have enough to mark the question as dupe so it can be closed, I have suggested a dupe above, could u close down the question, so we can know its sorted

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Barmer beat me to it